# Limpiar la consola en java

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy haciendo un menu en java con opciones, lo que pasa es que quiero que después de cada opción y hacer la ejecución de la opción, este borre la consola(borrando los registros que se hicieron), y vuelva a aparecer el menu para volver a ingresar otra opción
Por ahi investigue y esta la opción de flush()
este es el codigo

```
        do{///inicio do while
        System.out.println("Bienvenido");
        System.out.println("1:caracter() = charAt()");
        System.out.println("2:longi() = length()");
        System.out.println("3:compara() = compareTo()");
        System.out.println("4:ascendente() = sort()");
        System.out.println("5:descendente() = reverseOrder()");
        System.out.println("6:Salir");
        System.out.print("Selecciona una opcion para continuar: ");
        var = leer.nextInt();
        switch (var) {
          case 1:
            ref.caracter();
            break;

          case 2:
            ref.longi();
            break;

          case 3:
            ref.compara();
            break;

          case 4:
            ref.ascendente();
            break;

          case 5:
            ref.descendente();
            break;

          case 6:
            System.out.println("Ejecucion terminada....");
            System.exit(0);
            break;

          default:
            System.out.println("Opcion no disponible:/");
            System.out.println("¿Desea volver al menu?");
            System.out.println("1 = si o 2 = no");
            ref.v = leer.nextInt();
            break;
        }

    }while(var!=5);//fin while
  }//fin main
}//fin clase
```

Comment: adjunta tu codigo

Comment: listo @Dramaturgo

Comment: podrias limpiar la consola aplicando `leer.nextLine();` en cada `case` luego del uso de tus metodos `ref`

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar este código, a mi me funciona usando Visual Studio:

```
public class LimpiarPantalla {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /*No hacer nada*/
        }
           /*Introduce tu código desde aquí*/
    }
}
```

Si ves que queda un poco feo en el código puedes añadirlo a una clase e invocarla siempre que necesites borrar la consola.

Comment: Es muy interesante, pero como aún estoy iniciándome en Java hay cosas que no sé hacer, me gustaría convertir ese código en una clase o método independiente llamado "cls"  e importarlo (una especie de module de JavaScript) para simplemente llamar 'cls();' para hacer una limpieza completa de la consola.

Comment: Lo logré con  
        public static void cls(){
                try {
                    new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    /*No hacer nada*/
                }
                   /*Introduce tu código desde aquí*/
            }

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el siguiente código para limpiar la consola:

```
public static void limpiarConsola() {  
    System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");  
    System.out.flush();  
}
```

Edit: al parecer esto solo funciona si la terminal soporta caracteres de escape ANSI asi que probablemente no funcione en Windows.

Comment: lamentablemente no funciono :( pero gracias

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código te servirá si creas el .jar del proyecto

```
public static void limpiarPantalla(){
        try {
            System.out.println("Presione enter para continuar...");
            new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
            String sistemaOperativo = System.getProperty("os.name");
            ArrayList<String> comando= new ArrayList<>();
            if(sistemaOperativo.contains("Windows")){        
                comando.add("cmd");
                comando.add("/C");
                comando.add("cls");
                
            } else {
                comando.add("clear");
            } 
            
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(comando);
            Process iniciarProceso = pb.inheritIO().start();
            iniciarProceso.waitFor();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error al limpiar la pantalla"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

El código anterior básicamente lo que realiza es hacer uso del terminar de comandos de Windows (cmd) para limpiar la pantalla mediante el comando **cls**.

Ahora si lo que deseas limpiar es la sección donde se muestra la salida el cual es ([Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/)), cuando el cursor se encuentra dentro de la sección de salida debes presionar las teclas **CTRL + L** y notarás que se va limpiar la pantalla.
Para automatizar esto vamos hacer uso de la clase [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) que sirve cuando realizamos automatización de pruebas que nos permite controlar tanto el teclado como el mouse, especificamente usaremos los métodos `keyPress` para que se escriba las teclas **CTRL+L**, y `keyRelease` para liberar las teclas anteriores.

```
public static void limpiarAnt(){
        try{
            System.out.println("Presione enter para continuar...");
            new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

            Robot limpiar = new Robot();
            limpiar.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            limpiar.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
            limpiar.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            limpiar.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
            
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error al limpiar la pantalla"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muy interesante, pero tengo que salir del editor y entrar en la consola.  

Me gustaría que la solución 1 fuera un ¡¿método!? al que pudiese llamar y que borrase lo escrito (limpiase) la consola al llegar a esa instrucción, p. e.   

            System.out.println("algo aquí ...");

            cls();

            System.out.println("Otra cosa ...");

Esto permitiría poner cls(); al inicio y limpiar antes de hacer otra cosa.